# Symfony Error : Cache Key "App/Entity/User__CLASSMEDATA__" Contains reserved characters "{}()/\@:"

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm learning Symfony in follow this series of video : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjwdMgw5TTLX7wmorGgfrqI9TcA8nMb29

I'm work with Symfony 6.1.2

i've a issue in Security part , after this step, between 13:05 and 16:30 in this video https://youtu.be/5LfSTeyvyuM?t=785

When he try to connect in his website , he have a error message because he don't have account create in his database ( This is normal it's for the video ). But me i have a other issue. When i try i click to connexion buttom and i have a Symfony error
Cache Key "App/Entity/User__CLASSMEDATA__" Contains reserved characters "{}()/@:"

i've reread my code again and again but i don't find a caracters like this in the wrong place. The stack trace only talk about symfony component so i'm little lost ...

If you can enlighten me , i'll take it

Here is my view code :

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container mt-4">
    {% if error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ error }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login') }}" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Nom d'Utilisateur</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" class="form-control" value=" {{ last_username }} ">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="password">Mot de passe</label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control">
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Se connecter</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My Controller :

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{


        public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authentificationUtils)
        {
        $error = $authentificationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        $lastUserName = $authentificationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
           'last_username' => $lastUserName,
            'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

And my class :

```
class User implements UserInterface, Serializable
{
#[ORM\Id]
#[ORM\GeneratedValue]
#[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
private $id;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $username;

#[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
private $password;

public function __construct(AdapterInterface $cache)
{
    $this->_cache = $cache;
}


public function getRoles(): array
{
    return ['ROLE_ADMIN'];
}

public function getSalt()
{
    return null;
}

public function getUserIdentifier(): string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

public function serialize()
{
    return serialize([
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password,
    ]);
}

public function unserialize($data)
{
    list(
        $this->id,
        $this->username,
        $this->password
    ) = unserialize($data, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
}


public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getUsername(): ?string
{
    return $this->username;
}

public function setUsername(string $username): self
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

public function getPassword(): ?string
{
    return $this->password;
}

public function setPassword(string $password): self
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}
}
```

Comment: Nothing jumps right out but be aware that Symfony 6 made some significant changes to the security system including the UserInterface.  So even if you get past these errors your code is not going to work.  Best to follow the examples in the docs or if you are really into videos consider the symfonycasts.

Comment: did you try command `php bin/console cache:clear`? or try with deleting `var/cache` directory and reload page

Comment: @PinksNotDead Yes I have already tried but there is no change, I've also tried with a new clean project (just a loggin page) and I have the same error

Comment: @Cerad I have already met some problems with the tuto, because he work with symfony 4 so I've taken the habit to look the symfony doc at the same time

Comment: i had similar problem in past, but it was 1-2 year ago and don't remember its similar
maybe... its something with implementing UserInterface in User class, in my opinion new versions of Symfony can't menage this and don't need it, so change `class User implements UserInterface, Serializable` to `class User`

Comment: @PinksNotDead No. Just no.  The UserInterface has been split into several interfaces in Symfony 6 but you absolutely still need it.  The OP could save themselves some trouble if they just used `bin/console make:user` but for whatever reason they seem determined to follow a Symfony 4 video.

Comment: @Cerad I've the same error with make:user

Comment: Hmmm.  So why are you injecting $cache into the user?  Injecting anything into any entity is quite unusual.  I guess you need to figure out where this cache key is coming from.  The error message shows the cache does not like forward slashes.  But the real mystery is why bring a cache into this at all.